# Suggestions for how to host a public TensorBoard to present an ML prototype?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tensorflow, tensorboard

My current TensorBoard is only available locally, I understand I can ssh into my ML server and access the TensorBoard remotely. I am looking for a way to host the TensorBoard files on my webserver that doesn't have a dependency on the ML server, so that I may present the results of my ML prototype to those that have access to a web url. Ideas?

Comment: Where is your web server from ML server? In network topology? In the same network or machine? Or two different networks that need access over the internet?

Comment: The ML server is in my basement, the webserver is on digitalocean, they are not connected whatsoever.

Comment: For this topology, I would use SSHFS mount of the filesystem from ML server to DO server. You don't need to worry about the security as all data is public/private key encrypted. This may require allowing incoming SSH connection from the Internet on your router/firewall since you will mount from DO to ML server. Reverse order maybe possible but I haven't tried it myself, that will eliminate the need of allowing connection to the home network.

Answer (score 0):

You can just install Tensorflow (which also installs Tensorboard) on your web server and then just copy the Tensorboard files over from your ML server to the web server either manually or using `rsync`. This will not expose your ML server to the outside at all.